# Unable to perform successful Paypal webhook validation

Tags: paypal, elixir, phoenix-framework, webhooks, paypal-webhooks

I am working to validate Paypal webhook data but I'm running into an issue where it's always returning a FAILURE for the validation status. I'm wondering if it's because this is all happening in a sandbox environment and Paypal doesn't allow verification for sandbox webhook events? I followed this API doc to implement the call: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/webhooks/v1/#verify-webhook-signature

Relevant code (from separate elixir modules):

```
def call(conn, _opts) do
  conn
    |> extract_webhook_signature(conn.params)
    |> webhook_signature_valid?()
    |> # handle the result
end

defp extract_webhook_signature(conn, params) do
  %{
    auth_algo: get_req_header(conn, "paypal-auth-algo") |> Enum.at(0, ""),
    cert_url: get_req_header(conn, "paypal-cert-url") |> Enum.at(0, ""),
    transmission_id: get_req_header(conn, "paypal-transmission-id") |> Enum.at(0, ""),
    transmission_sig: get_req_header(conn, "paypal-transmission-sig") |> Enum.at(0, ""),
    transmission_time: get_req_header(conn, "paypal-transmission-time") |> Enum.at(0, ""),
    webhook_id: get_webhook_id(),
    webhook_event: params
  }
end

def webhook_signature_valid?(signature) do
  body = Jason.encode!(signature)
  case Request.post("/v1/notifications/verify-webhook-signature", body) do
    {:ok, %{verification_status: "SUCCESS"}} -> true
    _ -> false
  end
end
```

I get back a 200 from Paypal, which means that Paypal got my request and was able to properly parse it and run it though its validation, but it's always returning a FAILURE for the validation status, meaning that the authenticity of the request couldn't be verified. I looked at the data I was posting to their endpoint and it all looks correct, but for some reason it isn't validating. I put the JSON that I posted to the API (from `extract_webhook_signature`) into a Pastebin here cause it's pretty large: https://pastebin.com/SYBT7muv

If anyone has experience with this and knows why it could be failing, I'd love to hear.

Comment: Since you are getting a 200 response, then your pipes are working and you're probably missing something with the Paypal-specific payload.  You are posting ref'd JSON payload to PayPal's `/v1/notifications/verify-webhook-signature` URL -- but I don't see where you are setting the custom headers mentioned in their docs:
```
curl -v -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/verify-webhook-signature \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token" \
```
It would be helpful if you included that code I think.

Comment: I didn't include those in my post here because they contain my authentication data. I am posting them to Paypal though. They're added in my `Request.post()` function automatically and I use that function elsewhere so I know it works correctly. I have tried removing a field in my POST json and Paypal returns a 400, so I think I have all the fields (or else I wouldn't be seeing a 200)

Comment: X out your authentication data -- I ask to see that code because it's common for the custom headers to be borked, especially the calculation of the bearer token.  If nothing else, having sample code (with X's) would be a useful reference for others.

If you're getting 200 responses and you feel like your request is properly formatted, I would carpet bomb your code with calls to `IO.inspect` and see if you notice anything unexpected...

Comment: Here's the request headers: [{"Authorization", "Basic XXXXXX"}, {"Content-Type", "application/json"}]

Comment: It would be more helpful to add the actual code to your original post.  But just from looking at PayPal's example at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/webhooks/v1/#verify-webhook-signature they are using a Bearer token for their Authorization header in their curl example, not Basic authorization.  Are you sure that's not causing problems?

Comment: Yeah I tried using a Bearer token as well and got the same results. A lot of their docs mention Bearer tokens but Basic auth works fine for all of them as well.

Comment: I would add the original code but it's spread out across like 4-5 files and there's a decent amount so I don't want to just post a wall of code.

Comment: Have you tried substituting your JSON into their `curl` example to see if it works?
If the posting code is spread out across multiple files, that definitely sounds like the type of scenario where a bug can hide...  and nobody can help you spot it if they can't see it.  Maybe a first step is for you to simplify a fully functional version of it into something that would fit in a reasonable post.

Comment: Yes, I tried a raw curl. I actually found the solution and I am about to write up the solution as an answer here. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solved my own problem. Paypal does not canonicalize their webhook validation requests. When you receive the POST from Paypal, do NOT parse the request body before you go to send it back to them in the verification call. If your `webhook_event` is any different (even if the fields are in a different order), the event will be considered invalid and you will receive back a FAILURE. You must read the raw POST body and post that *exact* data back to Paypal in your `webhook_event`.

Example:
if you receive `{"a":1,"b":2}` and you post back `{..., "webhook_event":{"b":2,"a":1}, ...}` (notice the difference in order of the json fields from what we recieved and what we posted back) you will recieve a FAILURE. Your post needs to be `{..., "webhook_event":{"a":1,"b":2}, ...}`

Comment: Thanks, this is my issue.  Caused by me deserialising and re-serialising the body in c#; It was working fine, but the then a date came through with .41ms which changed to .410ms (and failed).  Fixed by excluding the body from the serialisation then appending as a string (inside the last })

Comment: This is good that you ran across this and took time to circle back with what the cause was. I bet this is what my issue is. At first I was disappointed that the PayPal API can't handle changing the order of fields, but since it is a verification I guess it makes sense. Because they probably compute a hash of it on their end, and when you call the verification they send it through that same hash, and from a hashing perspective difference in order matters. Modern frameworks will lead people to hit this issue, because the framework completely handles the serialization/deserialization.

Comment: Laravel guys can use `request()->getContents()` or `Request::getContent( )` to read RAW post data.

Comment: Here is a C# example of this https://gist.github.com/jsdevtom/562b1740164bae8e41f3bc37f28c5328

Answer (score 1):

For those who are struggling with this, I'd like to give you my solution which includes the accepted answer.

Before you start, make sure to store the `raw_body` in your conn, as described in [Verifying the webhook - the client side](https://dashbit.co/blog/how-we-verify-webhooks)

```
  @verification_url "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/verify-webhook-signature"
  @auth_token_url "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"

 defp get_auth_token do
    headers = [
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Accept-Language": "en_US"
    ]

    client_id = Application.get_env(:my_app, :paypal)[:client_id]
    client_secret = Application.get_env(:my_app, :paypal)[:client_secret]

    options = [
      hackney: [basic_auth: {client_id, client_secret}]
    ]

    body = "grant_type=client_credentials"

    case HTTPoison.post(@auth_token_url, body, headers, options) do
      {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: 200, body: body}} ->
        %{"access_token" => access_token} = Jason.decode!(body)
        {:ok, access_token}

      error ->
        Logger.error(inspect(error))
        {:error, :no_access_token}
    end
  end

  defp verify_event(conn, auth_token, raw_body) do
    headers = [
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: "Bearer #{auth_token}"
    ]

    body =
      %{
        transmission_id: get_header(conn, "paypal-transmission-id"),
        transmission_time: get_header(conn, "paypal-transmission-time"),
        cert_url: get_header(conn, "paypal-cert-url"),
        auth_algo: get_header(conn, "paypal-auth-algo"),
        transmission_sig: get_header(conn, "paypal-transmission-sig"),
        webhook_id: Application.get_env(:papervault, :paypal)[:webhook_id],
        webhook_event: "raw_body"
      }
      |> Jason.encode!()
      |> String.replace("\"raw_body\"", raw_body)

    with {:ok, %{status_code: 200, body: encoded_body}} <-
           HTTPoison.post(@verification_url, body, headers),
         {:ok, %{"verification_status" => "SUCCESS"}} <- Jason.decode(encoded_body) do
      :ok
    else
      error ->
        Logger.error(inspect(error))
        {:error, :not_verified}
    end
  end

  defp get_header(conn, key) do
    conn |> get_req_header(key) |> List.first()
  end
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. For "storing the raw_body in your conn" I used the solution [from this Phoenix thread](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/459#issuecomment-862203762).